# In EF Core how to select specific column and also save

Tags: entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.0

I have the following SQL table

```
 ID INT  
 Status NVARCHAR(50)
 FileContent XML
```

Using EF Core i want to select `ID` and `Status` columns but without loading the XML column. *(since the xml data could be large i dont want to load it into memory plus it is not needed for the business logic im doing)*
and then set the `Status`

```
public async Task DoSomwthing(int id)
{
    // select only needed columns
    var result = await _dbContext.MyTable
    .Where(x=>x.ID == id)
    .Select(x=> new 
           {
              ID = x.ID,
              Status = x.Status
           })
   .SingleOrDefaultAsync();

   // do something here using result

  // Since i am not loading the complete entity 
  // How do i set the Status here to new value


 //Save the tracked changes
 await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();

}
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/48462746/861716

Comment: The link is about how to select particular properties..that is not what I am looking for..i think @David Browne  answer is what I am looking for ..i have not tried yet

Comment: If you often want to get "MyTable" data from the database without dragging along the XML content I'd go for table splitting. It's easy to forget that the XML content should explicitly be excluded esp. when there are more developers on the project.

Comment: i like the  Table Splitting option. I have never tried before but i will give it a try

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In addition to Table Splitting, which treats the content as a separate, related entity, EF supports updates of just selected columns.

So you can construct an entity with a subset of its properties, and then mark the non-retrieved properties as unchanged.  EG:

```
public async Task DoSomething(int id)
{
    // select only needed columns
    var result = await this.Foos
    .Where(x => x.ID == id)
    .Select(x => new Foo
    {
        ID = x.ID,
        Status = x.Status
    })
    .SingleOrDefaultAsync();

        
    result.Status = 2;

    this.Entry(result).State = EntityState.Modified;
    this.Entry(result).Property(nameof(Foo.Content)).IsModified = false;

    //Save the tracked changes
    await this.SaveChangesAsync();

}
```

Answer (score -1):

1. You should create a new class with the columns that you want
2. Use auto mapper

Check auto mapper documentation
This Worked for me:

```
var teacher = _mapper.ProjectTo<TeacherReadDto>(_applicationDb.Teachers.Where(x=>x.Id==id));
```