# How to delay (lazy) load a binary property byte[] in Entity Framework Core 6 - C#

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have simple table with key, name and binary content. I need to load the binary content only when needed. This used to be extra simple in Linq2Sql, but in EF core 6 I cannot find anything except lazy loading of navigation collection, which is not what I need. Am'I missing something or is this missing in EF core ?
Jiri

```
public class Content {
 public int Id { get; set; }
 public string Name { get; set; }
 public byte[] Data { get; set; } // How to delay loading this ? 
}
```

Command

```
ctx.Content.Select(x =x.Id==1);
```

Expected SQL is:

```
SELECT Id, Name FROM Content WHERE Id=1
```

Comment: Can you explain more about why lazy loading is not what you need?

Comment: Lazy loading does not work on plain properties, only on "navigational one". On trial to use it there is and error:
The property 'Content.Data' is being accessed using the 'Reference' or 'Collection' method, but is defined in the model as a non-navigation. Use the 'Property' method to access non-navigation properties

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/table-splitting

Comment: Navigational properties means property pointing to other table, let say "Alias":
public ICollection<Alias> Aliases { get; set; }
As seen here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/lazy#lazy-loading-without-proxies

Comment: Table splitting is not exactly what I need. I cannot change the DB schema, since I am not the only user (and previously with Linq2Sql there was no problem)...

Comment: OK, I'll remove my "Data" column from Model, but still I'd like to keep my column being created by EF migration would it be manageble by UP/DOWN to remain in untouched and created in new DB, or I have bad luck with this as well ?

Comment: Probably you have to learn LINQ, there is not too much operators, `Select` for projection, `Where` for filter.

Comment: OK, I have codebase migrating from Linq2Sql to EFc6, with roughly 3000 linq queries - do not want them rewrite all. I am just surprised that such simple thing like property-lazy-loading is missing in EFc after 6 iterations...

Comment: I think you might have misunderstood the table splitting mentioned earlier. It's more like you have two different c# entities sharing the same unaltered table in the DB. The "lite" entity uses some column set X, the "full fat" entity uses some column set Y.

Comment: As Syvatoslav mentions to you could also just select a subset of the columns from the table for regular use and on more limited demand load a different set (including the large column) when you need the json data..

Comment: The given c# would not generate the expected sql. For an sql of `SELECT Id, Name FROM Content WHERE Id=1` you're looking at something more like `ctx.Contents.Where(x => x.Id==1).Select(x => new Content{ Id = x.Id, Name = x.Name })`. Be careful saving. see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48937489/in-ef-core-how-to-select-specific-column-and-also-save

Comment: Unfortunately projection prevents updating (and requires lot of rewrite even for reading scenario for me).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The only way to optionally load something is to use navigation property.

The solution in your case is fake entity containing just the `byte[]` property and configured with [table splitting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/table-splitting) to share the same table with the primary entity.

Note that this is just logical separation and does not require DB schema changes. The very first line in the table splitting documentations states:

> EF Core allows to map two or more entities to a single row. This is called *table splitting* or *table sharing*.

Probably you are confused with the term splitting. It's not splitting the physical table in the database, but splitting (sharing) it between several entities.

e.g.

*Model*

```cs
public class Content
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ContentData Data { get; set; }
}

public class ContentData
{
    public byte[] Data { get; set; }
}
```

*Configuration*

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity<ContentData>()
    .ToTable("Content"); // must be the same as for Content entity
modelBuilder.Entity<ContentData>()
    .Property<int>("ContentId");
modelBuilder.Entity<ContentData>()
    .HasKey("ContentId");

modelBuilder.Entity<Content>()
    .HasOne(e => e.ContentData)
    .WithOne()
    .HasForeignKey<ContentData>("ContentId");
```

Now the `Content.Data` won't be loaded automatically, and you can use the usual `Include` to load it when needed. The only drawback is one additional object instance and actual `byte[]` property accessor - `content.Data.Data` vs the original `content.Data`.

Comment: This works as long as Content is not an owned entity