# Select only specific columns from included table in Entity Framework Core

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

If I have this

```
var selectedEntities = db.MyEntities.Include(item => item.RelatedEntities);
```

It will load all properties (columns) in MyEntities but also all properties in ReleatedEntities. If I only need one property from RelatedEntities, how would I specify that?

Comment: `Include` is all or nothing. If you need one property, use DTOs and  projection (`Select`).

Comment: Maybe something like `var selectedEntities = db.MyEntities.Include(item => item.RelatedEntities.Select(x => x.Property));` could be useful.

Comment: Did you get any solution? I want to do the same thing. Want to load Employee data with Role Name only, but Include load entire Role object with Employee object

Comment: @Priya I load the related entities in a separate query. My related table contained a binary field containing files so this was much faster.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use .Select() and anonymous type to restrict the columns you want

```
var result = await _appDbContext.Companies
            .AsNoTracking()
            .Select(company => new
            {
                Company = company,
                EmployeeIds = company.Employees.Select(emp => emp.Id)
            })
            .ToListAsync()
            .ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, since it also generated a very efficient query.

Answer (score 4):

I was looking for the same, and after referring to other questions it seems like it's not possible. The understanding i got is that an EF entity is represented by the collection of it's properties, and hence loading individual values will not fully define the Entity.

To load only selected properties, we need to use **Select** query, instead of loading the related data. The query will result in an anonymous type.

**Note :** If the resulting type contains any entity, then the changes will be tracked. Refer [Tracking and projections](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/tracking#tracking-and-projections)

**References :**

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/basic-linq-query-operations#selecting-projections
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/projection-operations
- [How to include only selected properties on related entities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48462746/how-to-include-only-selected-properties-on-related-entities)
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/tracking#tracking-and-projections