# Anyway to require EF Core to use two queries for related data instead of 1 or N+1?

Tags: c#, sql, .net, database, entity-framework

Simple scenario of `Category` and `Product` (one-to-many). `Category` has a `Description` field that may be a long text. Now I need to query a list of categories with all their products. [Explicit loading documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data#explicit-loading) mentions two obvious approaches which are not good in my case (see below).

## My approach

```
var categories = await dc.Categories
    .AsNoTracking()
    .ToListAsync();

var catDict = categories.ToDictionary(q => q.Id);
var catIds = catDict.Keys;

var products = await dc.Products
    .Where(q => catIds.Contains(q.CategoryId))
    .ToListAsync();

foreach (var product in products)
{
    // Category.Products is initialized with empty List already
    catDict[product.CategoryId].Products.Add(product);
}
```

This approach only needs two queries and do not have redundant data. I am still happy even if EF Core could pull a JOIN but select only `Id` of `Category` instead.

Is there any method/command/query in EF Core that asks it to query related data this way?

---

Other approaches mentioned:

## 1 query approach

```
var categories = await dc.Categories
    .AsNoTracking()
    .Include(q => q.Products)
    .ToListAsync();
```

This one generates only one DB call but there are too much redundant data:

[image]

## N+1 queries approach

```
var categories = await dc.Categories
    .AsNoTracking()
    .ToListAsync();

foreach (var category in categories)
{
    category.Products = await dc.Products
        .Where(q => q.CategoryId == category.Id)
        .ToListAsync();
}
```

This approach removes redundant data but now there are N+1 DB calls.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to query for certain columns, you can use .Select to select only those.

Consider your example which uses .Include:

```
var categories = await dc.Categories
    .AsNoTracking()
    .Include(q => q.Products)
    .ToListAsync();
```

Since you didn't specify which columns to select, it retrieves *.

If you use .Select, then your query will retrieve only what you want to select.

```
dc.Categories
    .Select(c => new Category
    {
        Id = c.Id,
        Products = c.Select(p => new Product
        {
            ... all product properties you want to retrieve
        })
    })
    .ToDictionary(c => c.Id)
```

(add your `AsNoTracking` and `Async` where needed)

See also

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/basic-linq-query-operations#selecting-projections
- [How to include only selected properties on related entities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48462746/how-to-include-only-selected-properties-on-related-entities)

Comment: The problem is that if I still need Category Description (or any other column), there still is still redundant data. If I do a Select like your suggestion, I still have to merge 2 List together, so it's just like my approach in the question, just different code/query.